# Increase API rate limit for a user Community Managment API

Tags: linkedin-api, rate-limiting

I've set up a developer application and have addedthe Community Managment API but I am limited to making 10 API requests per user on most endpoints. Is there any way to increase this rate limit? Or is there an alternative way to retrieve data about engagements from our posts programmatically.

I am using this request to retrieve all the posts from my organization:
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts
I am using this request to retrieve reactions to each post
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/socialActions/